# Php return segment of string

Tags: php

I need to create a file with all the chat messages like `Lancha` that come after `[text] =>` that will be displayed through the php output. The example below is the Terminal or CMD output, but the real one is much more extensive.

On this example I would need to return `Lancha`.

```
[messages] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [chat_message] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [body] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [type] => text
                                                [text] => Lancha
                                            )
```

The `[messages] => Array` is repeated many times throughout the file.txt. But the `[text] =>` may or may not be present.

By now I have this:

```
$mystring = "file.txt";
$findme   = "[text] =>";
$pos = strpos($mystring, $findme);
if ($pos === false) {
    echo "No conversations";
} else {
    return $conv;
}
```

How could I return only the string after the `[text] =>`.??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Given that the content of the text file you are showing appears to be a serialized PHP data structure, you can use the following to get the data:</strike>

```
$mystring = "file.txt";
$conversations = unserialize( file_get_contents($mystring) );
if ( count($conversations["messages"]) <= 0 ) {
    echo "No Conversations";
} else {
    /* access the desired member in the object here */
}
```

The complete content of the file is now in an object array that is accessible via normal PHP methods.

For example, you could look through the array of messages and grab the text using the arrow operator, since the data is now an object:

```
$conversations->messages[$i]->chat_message->body->text;
```

**EDIT:**

Previously, your question said you had a file containing the data structure when the opposite was apparently true. To loop through the data structure and output the properties of `[text]` to a file, this should do what you need

```
$myfile = "file.txt";
for($i = 0; $i < count($messages); $i++) {
    file_put_contents($myfile, $messages[$i]->chat_message->body->text + "\n", FILE_APPEND);
}
```

Comment: First of all thanks. But imagine the Lancha'  is actually a sentence with many words. How could I access to the entire sentence? @justinpearce

Comment: @PiloBasualdo I've updated my answer. As I said, since the data is now an object, it can be accessed as such in PHP using the arrow operator.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much.

Comment: Sorry, I´m having trouble understanding the use of :$conversations->messages[$i]->chat_message->body->text; . How do you applie it.?

Comment: @PiloBasualdo Without knowing the requirements of your code, I can't go farther into implementation. You could loop through all the elements in `messages` and get each `chat_message` object and it's members. How to use it is dependent on what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @PiloBasualdo I have updated my answer to reflect the change in requirements.

Comment: Perfect. I'll work io it as soon as I get hands on my computer. Thanks

Comment: I´m getting this error: unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 5334040 bytes in

Comment: @PiloBasualdo The code that unserializes was not taking into account the fact that you already had the object in memory and needed to output it to a file. The previous code assumed you were reading the serialized data from a file. I have updated the answer.